# Filling forms in an IE Window: Press buttons and fill in text boxes

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to automate filling in an IE site that is repetitive and time consuming.

I wrote code that launches IE, makes it visible to the user, Dims the variables that it needs to fill in.

I have found the ID and the name of the text box but I cannot fill it in.

The site is a corporate site so I cannot attach the link.

I can attach the HTLM code of the box I am trying to fill and button I'm am trying to click.

TEXT BOX

```
<input name="ctl00$m$g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af$ctl00$grdLineItems$ctl02$txtDescription" 
 type="text"
 id="ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_grdLineItems_ctl02_txtDescription"
 class="txtDescription" 
 onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" 
 style="width:680px;margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px" />
```

BUTTON CLICK

```
<input type="submit"
 name="ctl00$m$g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af$ctl00$ButtonAdd" 
 value="Add New Item"
 id="ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_ButtonAdd"
 style="color:Black;background-color:White;font-size:Medium;font-weight:bold;width:150px;"/>
```

I tried different ways. I tried getting the text box by name but I am getting an error on the document command.

MY CODE

```
Sub Fill_in_eShipper()

Dim IE As Object Dim web_address As String
Dim number_of_elements As Integer 
Dim MydataSet As Variant 
Dim ObjCollection As Object 

Windows("eshipper filler.xlsm").Activate

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

web_address = Range("c2") Range("D2").Formula = "=ROWS(A1:A161)-1"
number_of_elements = Range("d2") 

IE.navigate web_address 
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy DoEvents 'Wait till IE is done loading Wend

'Number of elements to populate 
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 

Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=ROWS(RC[-3]:R[160]C[-3])-1"   

IE.document.getelementsbyid("ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_grdLineItems_ctl02_txtDescription").Value = Range("A2")
IE.document.All("ctl00$m$g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af$ctl00$ButtonAdd").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - please make sure to add your code in the proper format so that we're able to view it easily - next time, just copy and paste the code from your module, highlight the whole block and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: And the syntax is `.getElementById`, not `getElementsById`.

Answer (score 1):

Try - changed `Elements` to `Element` and just stuck with `.getElementById` for the click as well.

```
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_grdLineItems_ctl02_txtDescription").Value = Range("A2")
IE.document.getElementById("ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_ButtonAdd").Click
```

Comment: Nice and concise.+

Comment: @QHarr Now I *would* use querySelector, but I just wanted to fix his minor mistakes in current syntax :)

Comment: Lol. Your answer is better for explaining the error and you went with the fastest selector.  And glad to hear the love for querySelector! Wup wup.

Comment: @QHarr Oh yeah... querySelector (and you) have saved me countless hours in this monstrous program that I'm wrapping up (hooray!).

Comment: Congrats on the progress!

Answer (score 1):

You have been given the best selector method in the existing answer, which is to use the element id attributes.

Here is alternate syntax for the same thing using the CSS on the page and id selectors ("`#`").

```
With ie.document
    .querySelector("#ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_grdLineItems_ctl02_txtDescription").Value = Range("A2")
    .querySelector("#ctl00_m_g_8fbfd2b6_3945_4bee_9a3b_20cfc2c846af_ctl00_ButtonAdd").Click
End With
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the pointers I have tried The query selector and I am obtaining the same error   Method 'Document' of object 'IWEBBrowser2' failed

Comment: Try declaring ie As New InternetExplorerMedium

Comment: Did that make a difference?

Comment: No, have been experimenting with the site looking at the variables I do enter manually. The value is non existent until you save and then it writes it. Before saving there is no value. is this common?